# How to get quoted text inside a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var examplestring = 'Person said "How are you doing?" ';
```

How can I get the string inside the double quotes. Specifically, I want a var that is set to    How are you doing?  in this case.

Comment: What about if the string is 'Person said "How are you doing?" and then said "any better?" '; ?

Comment: In my case, I can ensure there is only one set of double quotes in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var quotedString = examplestring.split('"')[1];
```

This will split on each ", into the following

```
quotedString[0] = "Person said ";
quotedString[1] = "How are you doing?"
quotedString[2] = " ";
```

And then select from index 1 of the new array, returning "How are you doing?" (without the quotes).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use regular expressions:

```
var match = exampleString.match(/"([^"]*)"/);

if(match) {
  var quoted = match[1]; // -> How are you doing?
} else {
  //no matches found
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the regex string and how it works? I'm curious.

Comment: The first and last characters, `/`, are simply delimiters starting and ending the regex pattern. The quotes are of course the quotes you are looking for. The `[^"]` means to look for any character other than a double quote, and the `*` indicates you want to match 0 or more of those characters, as many as possible. The parentheses denote which part of the pattern will be "captured". In this case there is only one capturing group, so `match[1]` is filled with the match. In English this says: "Find as many sequential characters immediately after a double quote that are not a double qoute"

Answer (score 1):

```
var examplestring = 'Person said "How are you doing?" ';
var extract = examplestring.match(/\"(.*)\"/);
alert(extract[1]);
```

Comment: Just FYI: this grep gets a bit funky if you have more than two double quotes.